# CVE-2014-6271 over ssh example attack?

Tags: bash, ssh, security, scripts

I've been reading about the CVE-2014-6271 bug on lots of pages, but I'm still not able to understand how exactly is it possible to exploit it over ssh.

From all I've read, I couldn't find an example that executes a piece of code without being authenticated.
I'm just trying to understand the bug better, no hacking involved.

As per
https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/

An attacker can provide specially-crafted environment variables containing arbitrary commands that will be executed on vulnerable systems under certain conditions. The new issue has been  assigned CVE-2014-7169.

Comment: some good info here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223

Comment: I read that one and the link in the article. They do both describe the diagnostic, details about the bug and how to solve it. My question is how do I run an arbitrary piece of code on another machine via ssh without authorization, as many articles suggest that the exploit makes this possible

Comment: "cracking" is almost certainly considered off topic here. Google search topics such as buffer overflows ;) The topic is moderately complex and not really conducive to this question / answer format.

Comment: Also , when reading "certain conditions" , those conditions may not be know as injecting code is not a part of the original design. The point is that it is possible to run arbitrary code.

Comment: Ok, can anyone provide an example of some conditions that would allow an attacker to provide specially-crafted variables that contain arbitrary commands? 
And an example of this kind of variables?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot circumvent authentication by exploiting this bug.

But SSH allows you to restrict what commands a user can run, e.g. by using `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config`. By exploiting this bug a user can circumvent this restriction and run any command she/he wants.

Comment: Not directly, but if one has shell access, privilege escalation can follow very closely. Also one does not have to have root access to cause problems.

Comment: So that would be installing stuff without being root, for example, right?

Answer (score 1):

The bug occurs when `bash` gets executed with a specially crafted environment variable.

Remote exploitation over `SSH` is only possible when `bash` is executed. When the `ForceCommand` SSH option is in use, that command always gets executed using the login shell of the authenticated user (see the manual page of `sshd_config`).

Vulnerable configurations include public git services which normally restrict you to just running git commands. With this bug, you would be able to execute shell commands, bypassing the `ForceCommand` restriction. For a git daemon service, this could mean that you can access all repositories owned by the system user (bypassing access restrictions imposed by, say, `gitolite`).